# Get the number of properties of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of objects that are generic because the size of the query columns can vary. What I want to know is the number of properties that object has to then generate an excel.

I tried it, but I don't know why it brings me 12, when the query has only 8 columns.

Response Rows

```
{
  "Comedor": "1.1",
  "APLICACIONES": "200",
  "ARANDANOS": "1000",
  "PALTO": "20",
  "TOTAL": "1220",
  "CAJAS": "101",
  "TAPERS": "8",
  "TACHOS": "25"
},
{
  "Comedor": "1.2",
  "APLICACIONES": "300",
  "ARANDANOS": "0",
  "PALTO": "30",
  "TOTAL": "330",
  "CAJAS": "27",
  "TAPERS": "6",
  "TACHOS": "7"
}
```

```
public async Task<GenericResponse<int>> GetDespachosExcel(DespachoRequest request)
{
    var uri = $"/api/Solicitud/GetDespachos";

    var response = await HttpInvoke.InvokeWebApiAsync<IList<object>>(_httpClient, HttpMethod.Post, uri, request);

    return GenerarExcel(response);

}

 public GenericResponse<int> GenerarExcel(IList<object> data)
 {
     GenericResponse<int> response = new GenericResponse<int>();
     string rootFolder = _environment.WebRootPath;
     string fileName = @"ExportDespacho.xlsx";
     //get property length
    var length = data[0].GetType().GetProperties().Length;
    ....
 }
```

Comment: Have you been experimenting with `dynamic` instead of `object`, yet? I am really not sure, what could cause that descripancy. Have you logged out the actual Type name and all of the Property Names? That might bring light into this.

Comment: What is the type returned by `GetType()` here? I suspect it isn't the type you think it is, and is likely `JObject` or something similar.

Comment: Also, is HttpInvoke something written by you or is it a Lib you are using?

Comment: It is something written by me

Comment: If it's JSON being deserialised, then this is almost certainly a `JObject`. If you do `var typeName = data[0].GetType().Name;`, what is that value?

Comment: So you need to deserialise into something more concrete (e.g. `IList<MyType>`) or directly use `IList<JObject>` and then you can do perhaps `data[0].Properties.Count()`

Comment: thanks, It would be good if you write the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

The post shows an http request. Here is a functional [mock](https://www.ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/generic-response.json) of that.

```
// Get a web response. 
// This http request string returns an identical response to that in
// the post, which IS valid Json (regardless of anything I've said in the past).

string jsontext;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
    new WebClient().OpenRead(
        "http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/generic-response.json")))
{
    jsontext = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Since the title of the post is **Get the number of properties of an object**: To achieve this outcome examine the deserialized `Dictionary<string, string>[]` to discover two dictionaries holding eight values each.

```
// The Json could deserialize to many kinds of objects.
// Dictionary<string, string>[] seems like a useful choice.

var arrayOfDictionaries = 
      JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>($"[{jsontext}]");
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfDictionaries.Length; i++)
{
    // For the answer to the question: "Get the number of properties of an object"
    // examine this object to identify 2 dictionaries holding 8 values each.
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"Dictionary[{i}] has {arrayOfDictionaries[0].Keys.Count} values");

    // Also give the dictionary a try. 
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"The value of APLICACIONES is {arrayOfDictionaries[i]["APLICACIONES"]}");
}
```

[image: Console output]

The second part of the question is **to then generate an Excel**. To make an Excel Spreadsheet without using the MS Office APIs, output the columnar data as a Comma-separated-values .csv file. This code makes the .csv file in memory:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

// Perform Linq query on the 1st dictionary to make a comma-
// separated list of the Keys (assumes both dictionaries are
// the same for the Header row).
lines.Add(string.Join(",", arrayOfDictionaries[0].Select(kvp => kvp.Key)));


foreach (var kvp in arrayOfDictionaries)
{
    // Perform Linq query on both dictionaries to make
    // a comma- separated list of the Values
    lines.Add(string.Join(",", arrayOfDictionaries[0].Select(kvp => kvp.Value)));
}
```

This section writes the file to disk:

```
var path = Path.Join(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
    "json_deser_generic",
    "spreadsheet.csv");
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

And if Excel is your default application for .csv files then you can open the spreadsheet in Windows Explorer using this command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
```

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

The working example is on [GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/json_deser_generic.git) leave me a comment if you see any issues with it.